# XQuery Error Handling

Tags: java, junit, xquery, osb

I've got the following Scenario:

XQUERY:

```
declare namespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";


declare variable $udgHeader external;


let $msg-name   := upper-case($udgHeader/msg-name/text())
let $recipient  := upper-case($udgHeader/recipient/text())

return
<recipients>
    <recipient>
        <dest>
        {
            if (($msg-name = "ARS_ISTP") and ($recipient = "ISTP")) then

                'IstpArs'

            else if (($msg-name = "ARS_ESM") and ($recipient = "ESM")) then

                'EsmArs'

            else


                error(xs:QName('fase'), concat("Unknown msg-name/recipient combination ['", $msg-name,"'/'", $recipient, "']! Please check fase recipient list."))

        }
        </dest>
    </recipient>
</recipients>
```

My incoming XML will throw the error.

This Error I want to compare to a File (expected Result) with Java (negative Test).

expected Result content:

```
Unknown msg-name/recipient combination ['ARS_XYZ'/'ARS']! Please check fase recipient list.
```

My problem is, that I get this error:

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlRuntimeException: weblogic.xml.query.exceptions.XQueryUserException: line 29, column 5: fase: Unknown msg-name/recipient combination ['ARS_XYZ'/'ESM']! Please check fase recipient list.
```

How can I handle this error to match my expected Result?

Answer (score 1):

The details of what happens when you call error() are a little dependent on your processor API, but in a Java environment I would expect your invocation of the query processor to exit with an exception rather than with a normal result. If you want a normal result, then return some element (or other object) that you recognize as an error result, rather than calling error().

In 3.0/3.1 you can achieve this by calling error() when the error occurs, and then catching it using try/catch at the top level of the query.